# Getting and setting a static variable

Tags: actionscript-3, static

```
[Bindable]
public class ProductsCache
{
    private static var _products:ArrayCollection;

    public function get products():ArrayCollection{
        return _products;
    }
    public function set products(value:ArrayCollection):void{
        _products = value;
    }
}
```

By the name of the class you see my intentions with this bit of code. I intend to set a "cache" of registries that I intend to use across modules and update accordingly. The get method is used for dropdown lists, the set method after a successful insert statement.

This works good for my needs. But I still need your feedback.

EDIT: I don't know what voting means here. Is this good code for its purpose? or do I really need to learn factories and dependency injections?

I was previously using a singleton for this, but I wasn't comfortable with that, I want to keep the singleton excusively for credential and config data. And use this for the rest of the app functionality.

Comment: Feedback on what? If you should use static variables? If you should do it like that?

Comment: Yep. That's important to me.

Comment: Damn it Jim, state in your question what you want!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a static variable will have the same effect as using a singleton!

Imagine if you had two instances of `ProductsCache`:

```
var a: ProductsCache = new ProductsCache();
var b: ProductsCache = new ProductsCache();
a.products = someArrayCollection;
b.products = anotherArrayCollection;
```

Now, because it's using a static variable, `a.products` will be `anotherArrayCollection`.

#### "Do I really need to learn factories and dependency injections?"

Yes, please, learn Dependency injection! You won't regret it! I don't think for this particular case you need a Factory pattern, but it never hurts to learn that too.

Dependency Injection is not that hard actually, the golden rule is: Whenever an object needs your `ProductsCache`, give them a reference to your `ProductsCache`. Don't use something like `ProductsCache.instance.products`. **Tell** objects about the ProductsCache you want them to use, don't let them **ask** a singleton about it. Very easy rule to remember: **Tell, don't ask**.